# Database Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to develop API from the database which already exists.I have got notice some of the IDs have a "Code" key word before the data type ( mostly "char"). Could you please help me to understand what "code" is doing? I searched for converting or casting but I could not find any ideas.
[image: this is the element]

Comment: It is really a question for the sql-server tag (not the C#, sql or api tags)

Comment: This really is a terrible question title. It has nothing to do with C# (you simply happen to be using C#). Then once you remove the reference to C# your it only has the vaguest reference to the actual question you ask. I would edit it for you but it would be completely different to what it is now - would you like to take a crack at it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Code(char(5))` means that there is some [user-defined type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the database, declared like

```
CREATE TYPE Code 
FROM char(5) NOT NULL ;
```

Then you have table like

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (AdminAccountID Code, ...)
```

In C# code you can use `string` for it